# How do I save a certain workspace as the default workspace (not default upon opening blender)

Tags: interface

I want to save the default compositing workspace a certain way so that when I open the compositor, it's the setup I like. I've figured out how to save the interface for opening blender however, I'm wondering: how do I save the default interface to only that interface (basically the compositor won't be the default opening blender scene)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any changes you make to any of the workspaces can be saved as part of your *Startup File*.

Here's my Compositing screen, I also enabled the denoising data passes so I could denoise renders by default.

[image]

Just open a new file, make any changes, and go to this menu.  Whatever workspace you're currently in will be the one Blender opens to.